# Tabularx: Aligning table-entries by a dot

Tags: tables, align, tabularx

I have the following MWE of a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*1c@{}*1c@{}*1c@{}*1c@{}*1c@{}*1c@{}*1c@{}*1c@{}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{col1} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{col2} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{col3} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{col4}\\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
&$a$ &$b$ &$a$ &$b$ &$a$ &$b$ &$a$ &$b$ \\\midrule \\ [-2ex]
title& & & & & & & &\\
type   
&$\underset{(9.21)}{0.26^{*}}$   
&$\underset{(8.45)}{2.34^{**}}$   
&$\underset{(-9.43)}{-1.75}$   
&$\underset{(-2.67)}{-2.43^{**}}$   
&$\underset{(-2.13)}{-3.17}$   
&$\underset{(-4.26)}{-6.58}^{***}$   
&$\underset{(0.38)}{0.14}$   
&$\underset{(4.12)}{5.32}$\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces the table as desired, where each entry contains two values: One above and one below in paranthesis. However, the issue is that the two values are not aligned as shown below in the blue circles.

Ideally, I'd like to align them by the dots (.) Is that possible? Maybe use some quick-and-dirty trick involving `hphantom` or the like?

[image]

Comment: unrelated to the alignment but use `tabular*` here not `tabularx` as you are not using any `tabularx` features, `tabular*` will give identical layout far more efficiently. (`tabularx` never does anything useful if there is no `X` column)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's the meaning of the numbers in parentheses?

Comment: @Mico These are t-statistics. The value above is the estimate

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated to the question but you are using `tabular*` syntax with `tabularx`, it is anyway better to use `tabular*` here.  Here I'm using a small helper macro to split up each number on `.` and set the two halves separately.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\def\zz#1#2{\zzz#1\relax#2\relax}
\def\zzz#1.#2\relax#3.#4\relax{%
  $\underset{\mathstrut\hfill(#1}{\mathstrut\hfill#3}%
   \underset{\mathstrut.#2)\hfill}{\mathstrut.#4\hfill}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{8}{c@{}}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{col1} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{col2} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{col3} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{col4}\\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
&$a$ &$b$ &$a$ &$b$ &$a$ &$b$ &$a$ &$b$ \\\midrule \\ [-2ex]
title& & & & & & & &\\
type   
&\zz{9.21}{0.26^{*}}   
&\zz{8.45}{2.34^{**}}   
&\zz{-9.43}{-1.75}   
&\zz{-2.67}{-2.43^{**}}   
&\zz{-2.13}{-3.17}   
&\zz{-4.26}{-6.58^{***}}  
&\zz{0.38}{0.14}   
&\zz{4.12}{5.32}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this technically works if there is only one row - but in the case of more than one row, then the alignment isn't correct across the entire column

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a compelling reason for typesetting the numbers in parentheses 30% smaller than the others.

I, too, would use a `tabular*` rather than a `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{input-symbols= (), table-space-text-post = {$^{**}$} }
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{S[table-format=-1.2]}}
\toprule
& \mcc{col1} & \mcc{col2} & \mcc{col3} & \mcc{col4}\\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
& {a} & {b} & {a} & {b} & {a} & {b} & {a} & {b} \\
\midrule 

\multicolumn{9}{l}{A medium-length subtitle}\\
\addlinespace
Type & 0.26$^{*}$ & 2.34$^{**}$ & -1.75 & -2.43$^{**}$ & -3.17 & -6.58$^{***}$ & 0.14 & 5.32 \\
     & (9.21) & (8.45) & (9.43) & (2.67) & (2.13) & (4.26) & (0.38) & (4.12) \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize Absolute values of $t$-statistics shown in parentheses.}
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. Some of my estimates have negative t-stats, but I get an error (`misplaced sign token`) when adding a minus-sign to one of the t-stats. Is there a way to account for this?